# How to stop devise users from deleting other users posts?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authorization

I have a devise user ( that I call a Provider in my app) and I am trying to write a custom authentication method to prevent the Providers from deleting each other's posts (called Procedures in my app).  Right now I have the correct_user method in my procedures controller.

```
def correct_user
  @provider = @procedure.provider.find(params[:id])
  redirect_to(provider_path(current_provider)) unless current_provider?(@provider)
```

end

I call it with the following before filter, also in my procedures controller:

```
before_filter :correct_user, :except => [:index, :show]
```

And I get the following error when trying to edit a procedure, even the provider's own procedure:

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `provider' for nil:NilClass)
app/controllers/procedures_controller.rb:8:in `correct_user'
Parameters: {"id"=>"523"}
```

From the looks of this error, the correct_user method is finding the procedure id instead of the provider id.  How can I fix this? Thanks

Comment: Not what you asked, but this seems more like an authorization issue than an authentication one.  Something that gems like `cancan` or `pundit` are focused on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Authentication** is about making sure that the user is who he says is. Devise is an authorization library. The only access control it provides is that you can make actions off limits for unknown users.

**Authorization** is making rules about who gets to do what. Popular libraries include Pundit & CanCanCan.

Even without a lib you could write a simple authorization rule like this:

```
class Provider < ActiveRecord::Base
  class NotAuthorized < StandardError; end
end

class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

  rescue_from Provider::NotAuthorized, with: :deny_access

  private

    def deny_access
      render 'some_view', status: 403
    end
end

class ProceduresController < ApplicationController

  before_action :find_procedure, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :authorize_resource!, except: [:new, :index, :show]

  # DELETE /procedures/:id
  def destroy
    # This line never gets run if the user is not authorized.
    @procedure.destroy
  end

  private 

   def find_procedure
     @procedure = Procedure.find(params[:id])
   end

   def authorize_resource!
     unless current_provider == @procedure.provider
       raise Provider::NotAuthorized and return false
     end
   end
end
```

Notice that in the `authorize_resource!` method you compare the user id of the record that you are authorizing against the user id from the session.

If you used the id from the params you're leaving yourself wide open to a spoofing attack where a user pretends to be someone else by passing another user's id in the params.

**However**, I would not recommend that you write an authorization solution from scratch unless you really know what you are doing.

Answer (score 0):

The error message tell you this:

Your variable `@procedure` is nil at the time that the method `correct_user` is called.

Comment: This is more of a comment than an answer.